# Using MP4 url with wavesurfer.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wavesurfer.js

I want to use wavesurfer.js in my Reactjs application. I get the video (mp4) urls for my application. I want to draw the waveform using wavesurfer. This is what I have tried but it takes around 3 minutes to get a waveform of 30 min video. It is too much delay. Is there any solution for this?

```
componentDidMount() {

    var mediaElt = document.querySelector('video');

    this.$waveform = document.getElementById('wave')
    this.wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
        container: this.$waveform,
        waveColor: 'violet',
        progressColor: 'purple'
    })
    this.wavesurfer.load("https://example.mp4")
}
```

Comment: You could use a lib that allows to create cached waveform on server side and load it on client side. This depends on your case. I'm not sure if this lib allows this. Possibly second `load` argument.

Comment: It depends on the **audio bitrate** of the video. A higher **audio bitrate** requires more time to render the `ArrayBuffer` of the sound spectrum of the video.

Comment: For example, in this image: https://www.pcsteps.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Compress-A-Video-To-Reduce-The-File-Size_02.png, the MP4 file **`Audio Bit rate`** is **`155kbps`**.

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution, but according to the wavesurfer.js [docs](https://wavesurfer-js.org/docs/options.html), there's the `partialRender` option which will "Use the PeakCache to improve rendering speed of large waveforms." So all you would have to do is:

```
this.wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
    container: this.$waveform,
    waveColor: 'violet',
    progressColor: 'purple',
    partialRender: true
})
```

I hope this helps!